# Lint found fatal errors while assembling a release target, adding a language xml file

Tags: android

I just added a new xml file for another language in my Android Studio project. When building the project I get the error:

```
Lint found fatal errors while assembling a release target.

To proceed, either fix the issues identified by lint, or modify your build script as follows: ... android {
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    } }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the translator typed wrongly a resource name. For example, where it had to be

```
<string name="Example">"This is an example"</string>
```

He typed

```
<string name="Exmple">"This is an example"</string>
```

So, "Example" is different than "Exmple".
Android studio could have provided more information about the error. It took me hours to find out. The xml file had hundreds of string resources. An error line like "*The resource Exmple is not defined in the default language*" could be enough.